# how to loop input tag inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

**this is javascript code inside which i want to print 9 times my select input field through looping in javascript**

```
        <script>
       var text = "";
        var i;
       for (i = 0; i < 9 i++) {
        text += "<select name="2" style="color:#000000; background-color:#CCCCCC ">
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
       <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>"

     "<br>";
     }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
      </script>



      <p id="demo">  </p>
```

**plz tell me whats the best way to do this**

Comment: **1.** Note wrong quotes, breaking string. **2.** *Syntax error, missing `;` in `for`.(Fixed by edit)* **3.** Either wrap the code in `DOMContentLoaded` or move it to the end of `</body>`

Comment: plz correct it by writting so that i can make it correct and give you points

Comment: Please clarify or reword your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concatenate the HTML string properly,

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  text += "<select name='2' style='color: #000000; background-color:# CCCCCC;'>" +
            "<option>3</option>" +
            "<option>4</option>" +
            "<option>5</option>" +
            "<option>6</option>" +
            "</select>" +
            "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

Edit: There is no need to set value attribute explicitly when both value and text for an option tag are same - Mark Erikkson

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/7m4uyebL/)

Uff.. Ok.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <script>
      var text = "";
      for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        text += "<select name='2' style='color: #000000; background-color:# CCCCCC;'>" +
          "<option value='3'>3</option>" +
          "<option value='4'>4</option>" +
          "<option value='5'>5</option>" +
          "<option value='6'>6</option>" +
          "</select>" +
          "<br>";
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Incomplete answer. Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376405/how-to-loop-input-tag-inside-javascript-function#comment58458498_35376405)

Comment: it is showing this in my browser "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Comment: Yeah, wrap it inside of dom load event, put it inside Html tag, add meta with UTF-8, add docType in the top of your html, also don't forget to minify your file before production.  :\

Comment: plz correct these things in your.. i didnt get you like this

Comment: @SarbjyotSinghChahal See, you better learn some basic stuffs of html and javascript first and come back to advanced dom manipulations. That error is raising because of the placement of your script. place your script tag as a last first level child of your body tag.

Comment: @SarbjyotSinghChahal Plz ignore my first comment. :|

Comment: guys i am just learner and 16 years old.... plz dont behave like this.. i got stuck somwhere thats why i have asked you....

Comment: Just a tip, if the `value` of the option is the same as its display text, you don't need to add `value=`. So for example, `<option value='2'>2</option>` can quite simply become `<option>2</option>`

Comment: @SarbjyotSinghChahal Yeah its good to know that you are a young learner. But here in SO we cannot give you lecture on best practices or we cannot write you the entire thing from the scratch. Please read how to use SO. And my better advise would be, split your problems into smaller chunks and try to find out solution for each of it. This is how I done when I was learning javascript.

Comment: ok thanks .. but plz help me with man @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: @SarbjyotSinghChahal Here you go, COPY/PASTE/RUN. Any further info you needed?